# How does the Applicative instance for ((->) a) work?

Tags: haskell

Given in `GHC.Base`:

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
    pure = const
    (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
    liftA2 q f g x = q (f x) (g x)
```

How can there be a definition of `(<*>)` with three arguments? I thought it only took two. How should I parse this?

Comment: This is just S combinator from SKI basis of combinators logic.

Comment: `-XInstanceSigs` could help you. You can check full type from this slide on my presentation: https://slides.com/fp-ctd/lecture-6#/16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trade variables in the head of a function with variables in a lambda expression in the body.

For example:

```
f a b c d e = ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
f a b c d = \e -> ...
```

or

```
f a b c = \d e -> ...
f a b = \c d e -> ...
f a = \b c d e -> ...
f = \a b c d e -> ...
```

(all of the above). Since `(<*>)` has type:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (b -> c) -> f b -> f c
```

this means that if we take `f ~ (->) a`, then it means that:

```
(<*>) :: (->) a (b -> c) -> (->) a b -> (->) a c  -- f ~ (->) a
```

or more convenient syntax:

```
(<*>) :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

or equivalent:

```
(<*>) :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Here thus `(<*>)` is a function that takes three parameters: `f :: a -> b -> c`, `g :: a -> b`, and `x :: a`.

Comment: Hey Willem, sorry to hijack your answer, but I'm wondering whether you would be interested in [reviewing Haskell Code on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haskell?sort=unanswered). We have around 70 unanswered (read: unreviewed) questions at the moment and could use some diversity, since I currently review around 50% of new Haskell questions (and I consider myself at most intermediate). Another opinion would be highly welcome from time to time.

Answer (score 6):

`f <*> g` is a function. Defining

```
(<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
```

is the same as defining

```
(<*>) f g = \x -> f x (g x)
```